# Is incharge/encharge a word?

Tags: word-usage, slang

I always thought the word incharge/encharge existed but I noticed my spell check kept marking it as wrong.

Examples:
"Who is encharge around here!?"
The secretary is encharge of taking notes.

I find this confusing because "in charge" is two words which as a phrase does not literally mean what it describes. Is it considered an idiom?

Comment: Please take the time to check a dictionary before posting questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sense you cite, it’s two words: you are *in charge* of something because you have the charge (task/responsibility) of doing it.

‘Encharge’ does exist, but it means something else. Apparently, according to the OED, it can be a noun meaning ‘injunction’ (though I’ve never heard of this—it is marked as obsolete, too).

If I see the word ‘encharge’, though, I will normally assume that it is a verb meaning ‘to give [someone] [something] as charge/task/responsibility’:

> He was encharged with completing the project and bringing in the contract.

Even in this usage, I would not be very likely to use the word myself, but if I saw it, that is what I would assume it to be.

Answer (score 0):

[*encharge*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/encharge) is an existing word, but with another meaning than you intended.

The correct version is [to be *in charge*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/To-be-in-charge).